# Android - connecting two activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I'm building an android application, with two activities: MainActivity and PlayActivity. In the MainActivity I'm placing a MediaPlayer with a song, and in the PlayActivity I need to have a button "Stop" that should stop the MediaPlayer in the MainActivity. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can't have two activities displayed at the same time.

Comment: I already do, the song plays in the PlayActivity but I don't know how to stop it.

Comment: You show me an app with two activities displayed at the same time and I'll propose you for the Nobel price.

Comment: I didn't meant two activities displayed at the same time. I meant 2 activities running at the same time, the main one is running in background, while the second one displays.

Comment: That's also wrong. An activity doesn't run on the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android uses intents to pass messages between activities. See the [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) documentation for details. Basically, you want to start another activity with `startActivity(intent)`. But before starting the intent, you can add things to the intent, like extras:

`intent.putExtra(key, value)`

You can also specify an explicit or implicit action for the activity to handle:

`intent.setAction(actionName)`

When your receiving activity starts, you should check to see what the action or extra is (in the activity's `onCreate()`) and then handle the activity as appropriate. In your case, you would stop the song in one activity if the other activity sends some sort of `stop` action in the intent.